# Excel macro that updates other sheets from a master sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, cells, vba

I currently have a workbook that has about 100+ sheets. So I have a master sheet, created from a table of contents macro. The master sheet has a list of serial numbers from Cells E4 to E116.

Now what I want to do is to input the serial numbers that I have into the master sheet, and the other 100+ sheets will also be updated with the serial number in the Cell F4. Basically all 100+ sheets has the same page format, so the serial number will be updated into Cell F4 into each of the 100+ sheets.

I have code below that does that. But it keeps popping up a message

> Runtime error 9: subscript out of range

I'm not sure what and where went wrong. Appreciate if someone corrects this for me! Thanks a bunch guys!

```
Sub test9()
   Dim j As Integer
   j = 1

   Sheets("TOC").Select 'TOC is the sheet name of the master sheet
   FinalRow = Range("E119").End(xlUp).Row 

   For i = 4 To FinalRow

       Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheets" & j).Range("F4")
       j = j + 1

   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Indicating the line where your code breaks would be usefull !

Comment: @marc_s thanks for editing, i'm still learning!

Comment: @user1425241: glad you solved your issue. Btw, welcome to Stackoverflow. Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve this problem. It's very silly, actually. The line

`Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet" & j).Range("F4")`

It's `'Sheet'` instead of `'Sheets'`. Really a silly error there.